# PHP function not being called, am i missing something obvious?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function

i think i need a second pair of eyes.

I have some ajax calling a php file, and it's returning json. This all works fine. I'm then alerting the data elements i return for testing purposes. In doing this i narrowed down my function is not being called.

```
<?php

// database functions
$response = array();
$count = 1;

// connect to db
function connect() {   
$response['alert'] = 'connect ran'; // does not get alerted
}

// loop through query string
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

switch ($key) {
    case 'connect':
        $response['alert'] = 'case ran';
        if ($value == 'true') {
        $response['alert'] = 'if ran'; // this is what gets alerted, should be overwriten by 'connect ran'
            connect(); // function call does not work?
        } else {
            $response['alert'] = 'false';
            $mysqli->close();
        }
        break;

        case 'otherstuff':
        break;
}
++$count;
}

$response['count'] = $count;

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: you might want to consider passing $response to connect and then returning it instead of implementing the global keyword.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your `$response` variable is out of [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).. use `global` keyword inside your function to registering your outer variable(s)

```
function connect() {
    global $response;    
    $response['alert'] = 'connect ran';
}
```

or SDC's edit:

```
function connect($response) { 
    $response['alert'] = 'connect ran';
}

connect($response);
```

Comment: or better yet, pass it into the function as a parameter; globals should be avoided where possible.

Answer (score 0):

actually you defined the result variable but in another type and you also have another result variable at the top so you put data in $result[] but you try to use $result so your code may not give you the expected result.